# Powershell to Parse/Iterate Through and Combine Two Registry Keys

Tags: powershell, registry

Using PowerShell, I am looking to collect installed applications. This appears to be most-thoroughly accomplished by parsing the "Uninstall" section of the registry here:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

AND

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

A simple PowerShell to parse the data and throw it in tabular format for just one of these could be:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* 
| Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion 
| Sort-Object DisplayName | Format-Table  -AutoSize
```

What I would like to do, instead of having to run the above line to get both x86 and x64 installed applications, would be to combine both into the same output. Is there simple solution to this that would allow the same line to parse both registry keys and combine the data into a single table?

Comment: here is an example related to your question: https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-InstalledApps.ps1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See: `Get-Help Get-ItemProperty` and notice that `Path` is a string array

```
Get-ItemProperty [[-Path] <String[]>]
```

That means (like many commands) you can pass in multiple paths.  For example:

```
Get-Itemproperty HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*, HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select DisplayName
```

From this, you can get all the rest of the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing and exactly the answer I was 'hoping' to get yet not expecting. Thank you so much.